# Что нужно для того, чтобы в приложение можно было вкладывать деньги?

Tags: java, android, google-play, монетизация

Например есть бесплатное приложение в гугл плей. Хочу добавить такую функцию - для получения бонуса/фишек нужно заплатить n$ (например 20$) и у пользователя будет больше монеток, но вопрос - нужно ли проходить какие-то проверки/условия для этого?

Comment: [Библиотека для совершения покупок внутри приложений (Android In-App Billing v.3)](https://habrahabr.ru/post/233265/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно открыть документацию по встроенным покупкам и узнать что:

1. Надо добавить сервис (через добавление `.aidl` файла) для связи с GooglePlay
2. Нужно в консоли создать товар
3. Нужно в коде запросить маркет на предмет возможных покупок.
4. Нужно инициировать заказ товара, чтобы юзеру открылся интерфейс покупки.